# Writing into Many-to-Many relation in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

Sorry if the question might be a dublicate but I didn't find anything relevant to my specific issue. So, I get data from an oline DB and want to save data in core data in case user don't internet connection. I get a list of meetings which I looks like this

```
"city": city_name, 
"location": some_meeting_room, 
"streams": multiple_streams, 
"videoUrl": no url, 
"contentUrl": no url, 
"description": very good event, 
"speakers": multiple_speakers, 
"title": title, 
"endTime": 1519290000000, 
"guid": aaaa551f-67c9-480a-9e39-c5c680a53039, 
"office": office_name, 
"startTime": 1519286400000
```

I have already created the entities for meeting, location, speaker, office, city and speaker.

My problem is related to Manu-to-Many relationship in coredata. For example one meeting ca be afiliated to 3 streams and have 2 speakers. The issue is how can I write that in data base as I populate all entities at ones, from the meeting. Should I instead have already saved in DB all stream, locations, offices, cities and speakers and then just add the meeting from the server? And if so how can I indicate a meeting that it should inheritance multiple streams/speakers from another entity.

Sorry for a long post, I've tried to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using CoreData you are working with a managed object context object when fetching, inserting, updating and deleting objects and not against a database so when you're creating (inserting) new objects in the context it is not relevant in what order you do it. CoreData will take care of that and make sure objects gets properly stored in the database without breaking any constraints.

So if you have your managed object context moc the following (rather incomplete eaxample) is ok

```
let meeting = Meeting(context: moc)
//... set some meeting properties
let speaker1 = Speaker(context: moc)
let speaker2 = Speaker(context: moc)
meeting.addToSpeakers(speaker1)
meeting.addToSpeakers(speaker2)
```

That the meeting is created first makes no difference here and it isn't until you save your context that the objects gets inserted in the database.

```
moc.save()
```

Of course you need to check first that the speaker doesn't already exist from an earlier meeting by trying to fetch each speaker first.

Comment: So, in the end the physical representation of the object will be something like this: stream: ios, java, .net; when fetching the meeting object and printing it.

Comment: Yes, looking from a single meeting it will have a collection of streams and a collection of speakers